# Replacing <li> elements with result from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="category-top-navigation__group category-top-navigation__group--level-2 " data-category="jj-brands">
  <li data-group="accessories">Scarf</li>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Shorts</li>
  <li data-group="tops">Polo</li>
  <li data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Jeans</li>
  <li data-group="accessories">Sunglasses</li>
</ul>
```

I have made some JavaScript logic which I use to get all the `<li>` elements and sort them into a two-dimensional array dependent on the `data-group`.

This means that the sorting would contain the following list:

```
"<li data-group='accessories'>Scarf</li>"
"<li data-group='accessories'>Sunglasses</li>"
"<li data-group='bottoms'>Shorts</li>"
"<li data-group='bottoms'>Jeans</li>"
"<li data-group='tops'>Polo</li>"
"<li data-group='tops'>T-shirt</li>"
```

Now what I would like to do is to replace the already existing `<li>` elements inside the `<ul>` with the new sorted list. And this is where I am stuck.

**[CodePen Example Here](https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/LBWBgX)**

Comment: What about with $(ul).html(new data)?

Comment: There's no jQuery tag in the OP @Programmer

Comment: So without jquery - document.getElementById(ul).innerHTML = new data

Comment: Then post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `ul`s `innerHTML` using a joined `Array` created from the `li`-elements that is sorted on its elements using the `data-group` attribute, mapped to to strings from the elements `outerHTML`.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
ul.innerHTML = Array.from(ul.querySelectorAll("li"))
  .sort( (a, b) => a.dataset.group.localeCompare(b.dataset.group) )
  .map(v => v.outerHTML)
  .join("");
```

```html
<ul class="category-top-navigation__group category-top-navigation__group--level-2 " data-category="jj-brands">
  <li data-group="accessories">Scarf</li>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Shorts</li>
  <li data-group="tops">Polo</li>
  <li data-group="tops">T-shirt</li>
  <li data-group="bottoms">Jeans</li>
  <li data-group="accessories">Sunglasses</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Kooilnc you anser seems to work nicely. I forgot to say that i could have mutiple <ul>'s, so I would need to run this each ul in the markup so that I dont get all of the results mixed up. Would that be possible with your solution?

Comment: Something like const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

for(uls = 0; uls < ul.length; uls++) {
  ul.innerHTML = Array.from(ul[uls].querySelectorAll("li"))
  .sort( (a, b) => a.dataset.group.localeCompare(b.dataset.group) )
  .map(v => v.outerHTML)
  .join("");
}

Comment: @MikkelFennefoss: perhaps you figured it out already: you can for example use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul")).forEach( ul => /*do the sorting and replacing*/ )`

Answer (score 0):

**[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/vaxVGZ)**.

You need to append the `li's` to your `ul` element after clearing it, like :

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul[data-category]');

//Clear your ul
ul.innerHTML = "";

for (i = 0; i < uniqueCategoryGroupNames.length; i++) {
    sortedCategoryItems[i] = [ ];

    for (j = 0; j < categoryItems.length; j++ ){
      if (uniqueCategoryGroupNames[i] === categoryItems[j].getAttribute('data-group')) {
        sortedCategoryItems[i][j] = categoryItems[j];

        //Append your li's 
        ul.appendChild( sortedCategoryItems[i][j] ); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```